# "a client and a doctor" vs. "a client and doctor"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, indefinite-article

I'm conducting a survey related to health care. You can describe yourself using 3 categories: a client, a doctor or "a client and (a) doctor." I'm wondering if I should repeat the second "a" before the noun "doctor" or omit it because I've already used it before the noun "client."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a list of single nouns, you can use *a* only for the first noun and omit it for all subsequent nouns.

*There are an apple, pear, plum and peach on the table.*

So, you can say a client and doctor. But you can still use a client and a doctor - it may even sound better if it's not in a sentence. On the other hand, in surveys, it may be good if all is made as short as possible.

Or you can say *a patient* and doctor, if you think this is appropriate to say in your survey.

Comment: We usually call the clients of doctors "patients" where I come from (UK).

Comment: I always believed that the term _patient_ should be reserved for an actual current relationship between a doctor and the treated person. I find it less appropriate to say, for example, "A lot of patients come in this hospital."